# Access default content in FullCalendar's dayHeaderContent hook

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I would like to use [FullCalendar's `dayHeaderContent` hook](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/day-header-render-hooks) to add something else besides the default generated content. The hook argument appearently doesn't contain such a thing. It looks to me that the [default content is provided by a private function](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/f6b0acf48f3f1283b4d5511b1b2f4ce42a555344/packages/list/src/ListViewHeaderRow.tsx#L51) so it cannot be invoked from outside.

Is there a way to do this without patching FullCalendar?

Answer (score 1):

It looks I simply don't need to use the `dayHeaderContent` hook, but rather the `dayHeaderDidMount`. Using that, I have access to the already rendered content in `arg.el` and using standard DOM functions I can manipulate it. I wonder though if it can conflict with FullCalendar's VDOM mechanism.